# Инициализация CoreData Stack

Tags: objective-c, coredata

Делал в приложении CoreData Stack по инструкции с сайта Apple:

```
@interface MyDataController : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSPersistentContainer *persistentContainer;

- (id)initWithCompletionBlock:(CallbackBlock)callback;

@end

@implementation MyDataController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    self.persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"DataModel"];
    [self.persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *description, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load Core Data stack: %@", error);
            abort();
        }
        callback();
    }];

    return self;
}
```

и столкнулся с проблемой, `persistentContainer` имеет свойство `readonly`, и в

```
self.persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"DataModel"];
```

не дает себя перезаписать, как так?

И я правильно ведь понимаю что `@interface` будет в .h файле, а `@implementation` в .m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы инициализировать readonly-свойство, Вам придётся обращаться непосредственно к самой переменной, которую Ваше свойство представляет:

```
_persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"DataModel"];
[_persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *description, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load Core Data stack: %@", error);
        abort();
    }
    callback();
}];
```

Теперь по поводу разделения кода на интерфейс и реализацию. Я бы сделал вот такой заголовочный файл с расширением "*.h" (ещё я добавил синоним для типа Вашей функции обратного вызова CallbackBlock):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(void);

@interface MyDataController : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSPersistentContainer *persistentContainer;

- (id)initWithCompletionBlock:(CallbackBlock)callback;

@end
```

А реализацию сделал бы такой (другими словами, содержимое файла с расширением "*.m"):

```
#import "MyDataController.h"

@implementation MyDataController

- (id)initWithCompletionBlock:(CallbackBlock)callback;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    _persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"DataModel"];
    [_persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *description, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to load Core Data stack: %@", error);
            abort();
        }
        callback();
    }];

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Так правда все заработало, спасибо. Но не пойму строку `typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(void);` Понимаю что это переназначение имени типа данных, но тут получается что `CallbackBlock` вместо `void`, так?

Comment: @StanislavK. typedef используется для определения синонимов типов. В простейшем случае Вы используете данную конструкцию так: typedef int IntegerType. В вашем случае я использовал typedef для синонима типа функции, что крайне рекомендуется делать всем разработчикам на Objective-C. То есть вместо того, что по всем Вашим методам таскать громоздкое описание типа функции (void(^)(void)), я определил для неё синоним (CallbackBlock). Если совсем непонятно, создайте новый вопрос и Вам обязательно дадут развёрнутый ответ с примерами.